# jQuery - Animation happening at one time

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have installed animate.css plugin for my website to animate divs, then i used jQuery.

The only problem is the animation is happening at one time after i load first div.

What i want is to load animation for each div once its scrolled to it.

I'm using this code

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('#shopify-section-1514231356920, #shopify-section-1514232991457').each( function(i){
            $('#shopify-section-1514231356920, #shopify-section-1514232991457').addClass('animated slideInRight'); 

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});
```

CSS:

```
#shopify-section-1514231356920, #shopify-section-1514232991457 {
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
opacity: 0;
  }
```

Comment: It is fading correctly on scrolling on jsfiddle, and on edge browser.

Comment: yes i know but as i said i use animation.css plugin which is happening at once but i want the animation happend for each div.